# jQuery datepicker positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I saw many questions and answers about datepicker positioning, but cannot find answer to my situation.

So, here is my datepicker creator function:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        minDate:current_date,
        currentText: 'Today',
        firstDay: 1,
    });
```

When I click the input, the datepicker appears in right position, but when I reduce the width of the browser window, it stays in the same position(that's because it's position is absolute).

I need to change the picker appearance, so that it stays in the same position as the input.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post a complete code example please, including the relevant HTML and CSS. Also, a jsFiddle.net example is usually helpful.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gdr7Ljvt/

here is the fiddle, but I'm not sure it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that repositions the datepicker is found in the jQueryUI's `$.datepicker._showDatepicker` function. It's rather ugly, but not terribly difficult, to adapt it for a `.resize` handler. Here are the lines that makes the magic happen:

```
    inst = $.datepicker._getInst(input);
    if (!$.datepicker._pos) { // position below input
        $.datepicker._pos = $.datepicker._findPos(input);
        $.datepicker._pos[1] += input.offsetHeight; // add the height
    }
    offset = {left: $.datepicker._pos[0], top: $.datepicker._pos[1]};
    // and adjust position before showing
    offset = $.datepicker._checkOffset(inst, offset, isFixed);
    inst.dpDiv.css({position: ($.datepicker._inDialog && $.blockUI ?
        "static" : (isFixed ? "fixed" : "absolute")), display: "none",
        left: offset.left + "px", top: offset.top + "px"});
```

`inst.dpDiv` is a reference to the wrapper around your datepicker, and `inst` is the reference to the datepicker itself.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9k9pvqvz/) with a minimalistic example. Beware edge cases.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here and don't know the rules well yet. I can't upvote your answer because I have no min reputation :(